# Translation of "state" into German (software related)

Tags: translation, meaning

I need to translate the term *state* into German.

The context is following:

In a customer relation management software each customer can have different independent *states* such as "bad payer", "has premium contract", "important customer", etc.

Each of the states can be activated by a check box like this:

[image]

I'm hesitating between:

- *Status* (but there is no real plural for this word in German)
- *Zustand*
- *State* (just using the english word)

None are really satisfying.

The actual phrase to translate is not on the screen but only in the manual:

***Each customer can have up to 36 user definable states***

Comment: Isn't it more a flag than a state? Then you could translate it as "Kennzeichen".

Comment: This is not a state, unless you expect transitions between these states.

Comment: @CarstenS so how would you call this in English ?

Comment: Since those "states" are user definable and therefore rather generic, I would simply use "Markierung", or "Kennzeichen" as suggested by ladybug.

Comment: The [plural of _Status_ is _Status_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Status). The word is derived from a latin u-declination.

Comment: @simbabque If you talk about the latin u-declination you should also note that the `u` is then pronounced longer. At least that's what I learned in Latin 25 years ago...

Comment: I agree with Carsten that this is not a "state". I would call it "property" instead. The corresponding German word could be "Eigenschaft".

Comment: Go for "Merkmal", *everybody* understands this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would go with

> Kundenattribute

Comment: I would even suggest to use the term "attribute" in the English version as well.

Comment: "Attribut" is too much IT nerdish ...;-) A common (non-IT) German would not use this.

Answer (score 15):

Ich would translate that by

> Kategorie.

*Zustand* suggests a time dependency, *Status* would work, but is somewhat blurry,  *State* has far too many meanings and would require a concise definition.

Alternatively a compound could be used, as e. g.

> Kundenstatus

To reflect the somewhat shifted focus in the edited question: Here also the following can be considered:

- Attribut(e), which would also correspond to *class attribute*
- Eigenschaft(en)

Comment: _Kundenstatus_ sounds good, but how can you "pluralize" that word? "Kundenstatuten" sounds weird.

Comment: The plural of status is, well, status (read: *statūs*)

Comment: @Ingmar yes, I know, but most people don't and therefore it would sound rather strange to most people.

Answer (score 11):

I would use something like
Kennzeichen
or "flag"

Comment: Excellent. This is what's often used in real life in german speaking CRMs.

Comment: In the CRM I'm working on, there's for example the _Datenschutzkennzeichen_, flagging customers who rejected being included in any kind of marketing campaign, or the _Totkennzeichen_ for customer accounts that have been deactivated because the associated person has died.

Answer (score 11):

In computer science and software development, the corrrect translation of "state" would be "Zustand". However, this would sound very odd in german in your specific situation. The cause for that is that "state" is a poor choice of words in english for this to begin with (properties or attributes would have been much better).

I would go with "Attribut" or "Eigenschaft" in german.

The whole sentence would then read as

> Jeder Kunde kann bis zu 36 benutzerdefinierte Attribute haben.

Comment: I can't recognize, where this answer exceeds mine besides the final full translation, which I can't imagine to be the problem.

Comment: Your answer heavily emphasizes "Kategorie" and "Kundenstatus", which are imho very unsatisfactory. You only give "Eigenschaften" and "Attribute" as side remarks, and don't explain *why* they would be good, which my answer explains better. These answers are significantly different.

Answer (score 6):

I throw in

**Gruppierungsmerkmale**,

because all items are groups and flags to remember (grouping characteristics).

Comment: Or just short "Merkmal/e"? Best one so far, BTW! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I think I would refer to throw in:

> Merkmal

pural:

> Merkmale

which would lead to a manual entry like this:

> Jeder Kunde kann bis zu 36 benutzerdefinierte Merkmale besitzen.

Answer (score 3):

I would hesitate describing this as a *state*. I think this is better suited to be something like *additional information*. This would translate to *zusätzliche Informationen*.

I don't know your semantics but it seems to me, that one customer can have multiple states at once (eg. *bad payer* **and** *important customer*). This means that a customer would have multiple states at once, which is a weird thing.

Comment: Just updated the question. It _is_ "additional information" but I need the word for each of the states.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I don't see why *additional information* wouldn't work for one item... it would be *zusätzliche Information* for one item and *zusätzliche Informationen* for multiple.

Comment: _zusätzliche Informationen_ is quite close but it's not specific enough. _zusätzliche Informationen_ could be anything such as "Nickname", "alternative e-mail address" whereas the states I mean are purely "Yes/No" states.

Comment: @MichaelWalz what additional means is determined by the context. The context here is the text on the checkboxes.

Comment: Question updated again: the texte is not on the screen but in the manual.

Comment: @MichaelWalz so what, *Sie können zudem zusätzliche Informationen wie x, y und z angeben.* This clarifies everything. If you'd use any other words, you'd have to clarify the fields as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14521)

Comment: @Jan the question is, how to describe the information provided in the form. OP proposed some translation of *state*. I proposed a different word to translate because I think that *state* is the wrong word.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to RRZ Europe's excellent *Kennzeichen*, I'd like to propose ***Facette***, *facet*.

A customer can have many of those, and each of them defines the customer in some way that's orthogonal to all the other facets..

Answer (score 2):

In this case, what the cluster of attributes describes is a ***Kundenbeziehung*** . The last checkbox refers to part of the ***Vertragsstatus***.